# Window extraction alert is flashing with EXTRAC32 command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to suppress the "Extraction CAB" or "Extracting CAB" window that appears during some brief *100 microseconds* when I extract a compressed file, as shown below. I tried to redirect messages to `nul`, but the window flashes anyway. I don´t want to use other extractors as 7Zip or such.

Any ideas to get rid of that window?

```
@echo off    
set u=d:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfolder3\myfolder4
cmd /c ""extrac32" "my.cab" /L %u% >nul: 2>nul:" & del my.cab
```

I have also used the `/Y /L` option, to no avail.

**Annoying window flashes and, then, closes**

[image: Window that flashes and closes]

Comment: As far as I remember, `extrac32.exe` will always flash a window, however, in your case, you certainly don't need to run it in another `cmd.exe` instance, which would probably flash another window. You just need `"%__APPDIR__%extrac32.exe" /Y /L "%u%" "my.cab" 1> NUL 2>&1 && Del /A /F "my.cab"`. That assumes that the utility records success or failure, if not, you may need to remove the `&& Del /A /F "my.cab"`, and add it in the next line, like this `If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del /A /F "my.cab"`.

Comment: If you are using an up to date [tag:windows-10] Operating System, then you will probably be better advised to use [tag:tar]. For example `"%__APPDIR__%tar.exe" -xf "my.cab" -C "%u%" 2> NUL && Del /A /F "my.cab"` or `"%__APPDIR__%tar.exe" -xf "my.cab" -C "%u%" 2> NUL` followed by `If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del /A /F "my.cab"`.

Comment: @Compo Thank you. I have used your TAR suggestion, since it is also Windows 10 native. It is working now without any window or prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my comments as an answer.

As far as I remember, `extrac32.exe` will always flash a window, *(it isn't really  console app, and I think part of IE)*, however, in your case, you certainly don't need to run it in another `cmd.exe` instance, which would probably flash another window.

You just need:

```batch-file
@Set "u=D:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfolder3\myfolder4"
@"%__APPDIR__%extrac32.exe" /Y /L "%u%" "my.cab" 1> NUL 2>&1 && Del /A /F "my.cab"
```

That assumes that the utility records success or failure, if not, you may need to remove the  `&& Del /A /F "my.cab"`, and add it in the next line, as a result of any returned errorlevel.

Like this:

```batch-file
@Set "u=D:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfolder3\myfolder4"
@"%__APPDIR__%extrac32.exe" /Y /L "%u%" "my.cab" 1> NUL 2>&1
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del /A /F "my.cab"
```

---

If you are using an up to date [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) Operating System, then you will probably be better advised to use [tar](/questions/tagged/tar).

For example:

```batch-file
@Set "u=D:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfolder3\myfolder4"
@"%__APPDIR__%tar.exe" -xf "my.cab" -C "%u%" 2> NUL && Del /A /F "my.cab"
```

Or:

```batch-file
@Set "u=D:\myfolder1\myfolder2\myfolder3\myfolder4"
@"%__APPDIR__%tar.exe" -xf "my.cab" -C "%u%" 2> NUL
@If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del /A /F "my.cab"
```